# Laravel Testing Collection JSON Response with assertJson

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.7

I'm wanting to write a test to create a user then test if the user is shows within the Users API index collection using the route.

I've read through the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/http-tests#testing-json-apis) on writing REST API Tests with Laravel and PHPUnit. I'm having a hard time getting the `assertJson` to pass as it's returning the following error:

```
Failed asserting that an array has the subset Array &0 (
    'name' => 'Buck Trantow V'
    'email' => 'marianne.leffler@example.org'
    'username' => 'hhudson'
).
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
     array (
     ),
   ),
-  'name' => 'Buck Trantow V',
-  'email' => 'marianne.leffler@example.org',
-  'username' => 'hhudson',
 )
```

Test:

```
public function testUserIndex()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this
            ->actingAs($user, 'api')
            ->json('GET', '/api/users')
            ->assertStatus(200);

        $response
            ->assertJson([
                'name'     => $user->name,
                'email'    => $user->email,
                'username' => $user->username,
            ]);
    }
```

Route / User Controller:

`Route::resource('users', 'UserController');`

UserController:

```
public function index()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting here for anyone that needs it.. I've found that `assertJsonFragment` works for this scenario.

```
      $response
            ->assertJsonFragment([
                'name'     => $user->name,
                'email'    => $user->email,
                'username' => $user->username,
            ]);
```